# Edge's different coloring in a plotly graph

Tags: python, plotly

I have a graph and I'd like to have two different colors for the edges. From the [docs](https://plotly.com/python/reference/) it can be seen that this is done using the `color` and `colorscale` keys from the `marker` dictionary.

This works as excepted when giving colors to nodes in the graph. It is not working when I am trying to do the same thing with the edges of the graph.

I have something like this

```
edge_trace = go.Scatter( x=edge_x, y=edge_y, mode = 'lines',
    line=dict(width=1), hoverinfo='none',
    marker=dict(
        color=edge_color,
        colorscale=edge_colorscale,
        # cmin=0,
        # cmax=1
    )
)
```

The result is that the edges of the graph have some kind of bluish color that is not defined anywhere.

Any subtle differences when giving different colors to edges that I am not aware from?

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently one cannot do this the same way as it would be done with the `node_trace`. Separate `edge_trace` need to be created for every group of edges of different colors that one desires. If you'd like to have 2 groups of colors in your edges you could do sth like this:

```
edge_trace1 = go.Scatter( x=[], y=[], mode='lines',
        line=dict(width=1), hoverinfo='none',
    )

edge_trace2 = go.Scatter( x=[], y=[], mode='lines',
        line=dict(width=1), hoverinfo='none',
    )

for i, edge in enumerate(G.edges().data()):
        x0, y0 = pos[edge[0]]
        x1, y1 = pos[edge[1]]

        # Arbitrary distinction between the group.
        # Normally you need to have the indices of the groups of edges        
        if i < len(G.edges().data())/2:
            edge_trace1['x'] += tuple([x0,x1,None])
            edge_trace1['y'] += tuple([y0,y1,None])
        else:
            edge_trace2['x'] += tuple([x0,x1,None])
            edge_trace2['y'] += tuple([y0,y1,None])

edge_trace1['marker'] = dict(
        color='rgb(0,255,0)',
    )

edge_trace2['marker'] = dict(
        color='rgb(0,0,255)',
    )
```

Then combine into one for the `data` in the `Figure`. Like so:

```
edge_trace = [edge_trace1, edge_trace2]
data = edge_trace +[node_trace]
```

Comment: Also checkout [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/network-graph-set-each-edge-with-different-color/2805) for other examples.